# Proving the almost sure convergence of the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test statistic

Tags: mathematical-statistics, convergence, asymptotics

Context: I have spent the last few weeks thinking about how the central limit theorem is enunciated: if we have a set of **i.i.d.** random variables $X_1, X_2, \ldots X_m$ then $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^mX_i - E[\sum_{i=1}^mX_i]}{\sqrt{m}} \xrightarrow[n \rightarrow +\infty]{d}N\Big(0 \hspace{2mm} , \hspace{2mm}\frac{Var(\sum_{i=1}^mX_i)}{m}\Big)$.

What is drawing my attention is the fact that this statement is not spelled in terms of an *if and only if* condition; **therefore we might be able to come up with a set of non i.i.d random variables that nonetheless do satisfy the convergence in distribution above.**

Then I thought about the following setup. Let $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^{60}$ be a sequence of random variables where $X_i \sim \text{Uniform}(0, i)$. We define the random variable $Z = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{60}X_i - 915}{\sqrt{60}}$. I have devised a code in R for obtaining a sample of this random variable.

```
sample_z = function(n) {
  random_sample = matrix(nrow = n, ncol = 60)
  for (i in 1:60) {
    random_sample[, i] = runif(n, min = 0, max = i) 
  }
  (rowSums(random_sample) - 915)/sqrt(60)
}
```

We can, of course, after generating a sample of this random variable run a Kolmogorov-Smirnov test against $H_0: \mathbb{P} = N(0 \hspace{0.2mm}, \hspace{0.5mm} 72^{-1}7381)$ —which is equivalent to saying that the convergence in distribution does hold even though the conditions required by the central limit theorem do not—. **But there is an even better thing we can do.** According to Corollary 1 of [this document](https://math.mit.edu/%7Ermd/465/edf-ks.pdf) as the sample size goes to infinity the probability of rejecting an erroneous null hypothesis must converge to $1$. **Then, what we will do is try to approximate the probability of rejection of $H_0$ when the size of the sample of $Z$ is big.**

My code for computing the KS test statistic is the following:

```
ks_test_stat = function(n) {
  # Generating a sample of Z.
  x = sample_z(n)

  # Computing the ecdf and lagged ecdf of the data.
  data_ecdf = cumsum(table(x))/length(x)
  lagged_ecdf = c(data_ecdf[1], data_ecdf[-length(data_ecdf)])

  # Computing the theoretical cdf values of the data.
  quantiles = as.numeric(names(data_ecdf))
  theoretical_cdf = pnorm(quantiles, mean = 0, sd = sqrt(7381/72))

  # Computing the vertical distances.
  dist_2_empirical = abs(theoretical_cdf - data_ecdf)
  dist_2_lagged = abs(theoretical_cdf - lagged_ecdf)
  
  # Choosing the maximum of those distances.
  max(pmax(dist_2_empirical, dist_2_lagged))
}
```

Then, we approximate the probability.

```
# Sorry for the vanilla implementation; couldn't think of a better way to do it.
observations_ks = vector(length = 1000)
for (i in 1:1000) {
  observations_ks[i] = ks_test_statistic(10000)
}

# We will be considering a 5% significance level.
sum(observations_ks >= 0.0136)/1000
```

See for yourself that running the chunk above yields a probability of rejection that approximates $0.05$ rather than approximating $1$. There you have it. **$H_0$ is not erroneous.**

However —**and this is where my actual question begins**— this answer would not appease the Mathematician. From [a previous question I made](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/485139/does-the-glivenko-cantelli-theorem-work-back-and-forth) I learned that if we denote by $G$ the cdf corresponding to the $N(0 \hspace{0.2mm}, \hspace{0.5mm} 72^{-1}7381)$ distribution and we manage to prove that $$sup_z|F_n(z) -G(z)|\xrightarrow{a.s./p}0$$

then $H_0$ is *formally* proved. **My question is how can this be proved?**

Comment: "...therefore we might be able to come up with a set of non i.i.d random variables that nonetheless do satisfy the convergence in distribution above..."---indeed, the CLT holds under much more general conditions, starting with the classical Levy-Lindeberg result covering independent non-i.d. case. "My question is how can this be proved?"---Uniform (Weak/Strong) LLN.

Comment: Your sample is independent but not identically distributed. On the other hand, the distribution of the sample mean is known, perhaps you can study it.

Comment: @Michael, thanks for your reply. To my understanding the Uniform Laws of Large Numbers do guarantee the convergence $sup_z|F_n(z) -G(z)|\xrightarrow{a.s./p}0$ **but only if it is known that G is indeed the cdf of Z** (I may be wrong, though). In this case we don't know beforehand that G is the cdf of Z. We suspect it is, and we want to confirm it by proving that convergence.