# Difference between uniform laws of large numbers and law of large numbers

Tags: law-of-large-numbers

How to understand the difference between uniform laws of large numbers and law of large numbers? In particular, what does the word "uniform" mean?

Comment: Uniform LLN is a statement about sequences of random functions. LLN's are about sequences of random variables. One could view LLN as a (very) special case of ULLN, where the functions are constant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ...what does the word "uniform" mean?

Uniform refers to the topology (metric, if you'd like) of uniform convergence.
The uniform metric $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$ between two functions $f, g :X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is
$$
\| f-g \|_{\infty} = \sup_{x \in X} |f(x) - g(x)|,
$$
i.e. $f$ and $g$ are close when, well, their values are uniformly close across $x$.

For a sequence of random functions $f_n$ and a random function $f$, a uniform LLN is a statement of the
form "*$\| f_n-f \|_{\infty}$ converges to zero (say) in probability*".
That is, for $n$ sufficiently large, $f_n$ is uniformly close to $f$ with high probability.

One example of the Uniform LLN is the Glivenko–Cantelli Theorem, i.e. convergence of empirical CDF's to the population CDF, uniformly in probability. In this case, $X$ is the real line---possible outcomes of a random variable. This in turn leads to the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test. (You can find some related simulation [in this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/486149/proving-the-almost-sure-convergence-of-the-kolmogorov-smirnov-test-statistic)).

Another context in which one encounters Uniform LLN is MLE. In this case, $X$ is the parameter space and likelihood functions are random functions defined on $X$. MLE is consistent because the likelihood functions converge uniformly in probability to a non-random function that is maximized at the true parameter, with curvature at the maximum being Fisher information.

> ...the difference between uniform laws of large numbers and law of
> large numbers?

One can view LLN as a (very) special case of ULLN, where the functions are constant, but this is perhaps not the best perspective.